# Как изменить значения в переменой?

Tags: python-3.x

Есть уравнение

```
a = 5
b = 6
print(a+b) #5+6
```

Как сделать так если в переменной `b` значения отрицательное -6 он поместил его в скобки

```
print(a+b) #5+(-6)
```

Comment: вы о математике или о текстовом представлении?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наиболее простой вариант добавить условие:

```
if b >= 0:
     print('%d + %d' % (a, b))
else: 
     print('%d +(-%d)' % (a, b))
```

В вашем же случае будет выведено 11, а не 5+6.